# Dynaimic query in sql and how to implement it in view

Tags: sql-server, database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjpzo.png)My Query dynamically  create a list of skills in a single row.  However i can not use this query in view as  there are declare variables present in the query .How can i  modify it to use it in a view and still be dynamic

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(col + '_' + cast(seq as             
   varchar(2)))
    from
    (
        select  seq = row_number() over(partition by Skill.ID_Job
                                    order by Skill.ID_Job) 
      from dbo.Job_Skill Skill
      Where Skill.Min_Job = 1 and Skill.Ideal_Job = 1

   ) hr

    cross apply
    (
      select 'Skill',1 
    ) c (col, val) 
                order by val , seq
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'') 



 set @query = N'SELECT ID_Job, ' + @cols + N' 
        from 
        (
          select hr.ID_Job, 
          col = c.col + ''_'' + cast(seq as varchar(2)),
          c.val
          from
          (
              select Skill.ID_Job, 
        Skill.ID_SKL_Job,
        Skill.Min_Job,
        Skill.Ideal_Job,
        seq = row_number() over(partition by Skill.ID_Job
                                    order by Skill.ID_Job) 
      from dbo.Job_Skill Skill
      Where Skill.Min_Job = 1 and Skill.Ideal_Job = 1
          ) hr

          cross apply
          (
             select ''Skill'', ID_SKL_Job
          ) c (col, val)
        ) x
        pivot 
       (
            max(val)
            for col in (' + @cols + N')
        ) p 
        order by ID_Job'

exec sp_executesql @query
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjpzo.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to do but SQL doesn't support dynamic views.

Maybe using FOR XML and returning the result XML via output parameter in your procedure would work.

Then you could join the XML and query it using XQuery. If you returned a XML like:

```
DECLARE @xml xml = CONVERT(xml, 
'<jobs>
 <job id="1">
    <skill>s1</skill>
    <skill>s2</skill>
 </job>
 <job id="2">
    <skill>s3</skill>
</job>
</jobs>')

You could query for certain skills like:

SELECT 
    j.*
 ,  T.jobs.query('skill') AS skill
FROM @xml.nodes('jobs/job') T(jobs)
INNER JOIN jobs j ON j.id = t.jobs.value('@id','int')
WHERE T.jobs.exist('skill[.="s1"]') = 1
```

p.s. from what I can tell, using XML would allow you to scratch dynamic sql, since you could group skills by job_id from the start, having one column as job_id, second one as resulting XML, implement it in a view or inline function and then you can join by the id and query the XML without using any programming.